# Image uploading Not working In IE and form not submited

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, codeigniter

I have this code and working great in all other browser but IE. There was nothing happen and also i refer this link [IE image caching with jQuery form: Force image reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207090/ie-image-caching-with-jquery-form-force-image-reloading) then also not working

```
//jquery.form.js version: 3.10 .

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imageuploadform1').live('change', function () {
        var counter = 0;
        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif?c=' + counter + '" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        counter++;
        $("#imageform").ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#preview'
        });
    });
});
```

How can I solve this problem

Comment: What's not working? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i am using IE 8 and when i debug in IE i got the error like "script5:Access denied" in [jquery.form.js](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js) in line no 458 like form.submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not let you do much of anything regarding file uploads that don't use the native file input and involve the user physically clicking the submit button. This is a security feature in all browsers, but IE is a bit more heavy handed about it. It has been my experience that there is no way to do what you want in IE and you should simply put a switch in so that Non-IE users get the wiz-bang you're looking for, but IE users have to do it the "old-fashioned" way.

Comment: If any body have any other idea then Please share it..                    Thanks In advance